# $this not working on current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem in JQuery with $this.

I need it because i `append` different forms dynamically and i want to submit only one.

I use it in two cases, one work, the other not and i don't know why :

This one works, it submits the div I click on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultcontainer").on("click", "#DivResult", function() {
        $(this).find("form").submit();
    });
});
```

This one doesn't work :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".validedem").on("click", function() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure that you want to deny this film ? ")){
            $(this).find("form").submit();
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

where `.validedem` is the class of my buttons.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    {% for item in listerecueattente %}
        <div class="funzies">
            <form action="/app.php/start/go" role="form" method="POST" id="formulaire">
                <div id="appendit" class="container">
                    <div class="container col-lg-12 blueskycont mrgbot10" id="choixvalide">
                        <input type="HIDDEN" id="aTrajType" value="{{listerecueattente[0].DEMT_ID_PROP }}" name="DEMT_RED" >
                        <input type="HIDDEN" id="aProtRed" value="{{ listerecueattente[0].DEMT_TRAJ_TYPE }}" name="A_PROT_RED" >
                        <input type="HIDDEN" id="sqdsqds" value="{{listerecueattente[0].DEMT_NUM }}" name="DEMT_NUM" >
                        <div class="container col-lg-12">
                            <div class = funzies col-lg-6> {{ listerecueattente[0].PROF_PRENOM }}  sdq </div>
                            <button  class="btn btn-success col-lg-3 validedem ">Confirmer cette demande <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-white glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></button> 
                            <button  class="btn btn-danger col-lg-3 refusedem" >Refuser cette demande<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-white glyphicon-off"></i></button> </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    {%endfor%} 
</div>
```

Any idea why `$(this).find("form").submit();` submits only the first result of my list instead of the one where i click the button?

Comment: Is .validedem created asynchronously ?

Comment: `$(this).find()` should be `$(this).closest("form")`

Comment: Also, ids should be unique.

Comment: Warren what do you mean by that? I don't get that concept :s 

@Salman $this.closest() doesn't work either, it still submits the first one. Even though i get rid off the multiple ids

Comment: no need to manually submit the form , default behavior will do that already

Comment: You need to use `.closest()`. If you are creating new forms _after_ document ready (are you?) then you need to use delegation.

Comment: @charlietfl I will have two buttons so i will change the form action by JQuery before submitting it, this is why i do it manually, is there anyway to put type=submit on two buttons of the same form that don't make the same action?

Comment: action can be changed prior to the submit event occurring based on button clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- You are appending form elements dynamically so you need to use event delegation using [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- The button is contained inside a form and not the other way round, so use [`jQuery.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to locate the form that contains the clicked button

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".validedem", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm("Are you sure that you want to deny this film ? ")) {
            $(this).closest("form").trigger("submit");
        }
    });
});
```

---

Having said that, it is possible to use two submit buttons on one form. You can check which button was clicked on the server side. Submit buttons need to have different values.

Comment: Oh thanks it worked!! i had a small error in my template aswell and fixed it + used your piece of code and it now submits the good one :) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`.find` will only find descendents, in your case the `form` is an ancestor, so you could use `.closest`

[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree

---

Additionally, the default behaviour of a button is to submit the form it belongs to, it is not sufficient to `return false` you must also `preventDefault()`:

```
$(".validedem").on("click", function(e) {
    if(!confirm("Are you sure that you want to deny this film ? ")){
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

Yet another way is to attach the behaviour to the submitting of the form, but its more-or-less the same principal:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    if(!confirm("Are you sure that you want to deny this film ? ")){
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: My button doesn't have type="submit" so i thought i wouldn't need to preventdefault. And like i said earlier even by using closest it still submits the first form of my list... i'm a bit lost right now...

Comment: `return false` and `preventDefault()` do basically the same thing. No need to use both

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, i will use them now that i know this... And salman solve my problem aswell so i'm glag everyone helped me :) cheers and thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is in usage of "on" function, since you are using some framework, your html can be loaded asynchronously.

You've made right call using "on" in this case

```
$("#resultcontainer").on("click", ".validedem", function() {
```

You should use it same way here

```
$("any parent static dom element").on("click", ".validedem", function() {
```

Comment: This one only makes sense if the dom is being built after `onLoad`, which these is no indication that it is.

Comment: Yup i've tried it first but it still submits my first form... Even if i put id=resultcontainer on the div outside of my loop and in my loop